# how to connect phpmyadmin database with android application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I have asked this question before but that time i didn't have php file, now i have created php files and saved it on my xampp folder and its working i have checked it, the problem is in the code somewhere. I am trying to link my android studio register page with database but its not working. when user enters their details it should automatically save it on the database that I've created on phpmyadmin but when i click register on the app nothing happens. I am going to past the code below, please can anybody tell me wheres the problem?
thanks

this is my register java class

```
ublic class Register extends Activity {

EditText ET_FIRST_NAME, ET_LAST_NAME, ET_ADDRESS, ET_EMAIL, ET_PASSWORD;
String first_name,last_name,address,email,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    ET_FIRST_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFname);
    ET_LAST_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLname);
    ET_ADDRESS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    ET_EMAIL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    ET_PASSWORD = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

public void btRegister(View view)
{
    first_name =  ET_FIRST_NAME.getText().toString();
    last_name = ET_LAST_NAME.getText().toString();
    address = ET_ADDRESS.getText().toString();
    email = ET_EMAIL.getText().toString();
    password = ET_PASSWORD.getText().toString();

    String method = "register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, first_name,last_name,address,email,password);
    finish();
}
}
```

this is the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#8a73d5">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register Form"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#8a73d5" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etLname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btRegister"
    android:text="Register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and this is the background task class where the all code is for saving info(login and register) to database.

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context ctx;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx){

    this.ctx = ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Infomration");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   String reg_url = "http://192.168.0.10/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://192.168.0.10/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params [0];
    if (method.equals("register") ){
        String first_name = params [1];
        String last_name = params [2];
        String address = params [3];
        String email = params [4];
        String password = params [5];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("first_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(first_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("last_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(last_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("address", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8")+ "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+ "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Registration Has Been Successful.";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equals("Registration Has Been Successful."))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
else
    {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Insted of using asynctask to connect with your php, you may use volley library to automate the process. It would make http requests on its own and fetch the result directly for you. A good guide for introduction to it is : 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

After trying to get things done by asyctask, i switched to volley, and it worked in just one attempt.

Happy coding.